'Save' what light/dark mode was last active on a static html website
I have a simple toggle on my website, which when clicked adds/removes a class of .dark-mode on the html tag. Allows the colours of the page to invert.
The website is a simple, static website as that's all it needs to be right now.
My question is, is it possible for the last mode to be 'saved' so if I user returns the browser remembers and displays that mode by default?
If so, I'm not sure what the method would be for this - so apologies for the terminology (or lack of it)!


const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast-toggle');

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
});
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html.dark-mode body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

html.dark-mode a,
html.dark-mode a:visited,
html.dark-mode a:focus,
html.dark-mode a:hover,
html.dark-mode a:active {
  color: white;
}
<html>

<body>
  <p><a href="#" class="contrast-toggle">Click to Toggle</a></p>
</body>

</html>




Does this answer your question? How to store objects in HTML5 localStorage/sessionStorage

I previously suggested a duplicate question addressing localStorage in general. But since you are dealing with light/dark theme, you may still rely on the theme saved at the browser level using a media query and prefers-color-scheme to discover if that was set how-do-i-detect-dark-mode-using-javascript (SO)

Thanks for the previous post, as you mentioned it didn't quite work for what I needed. I just want this to work off what the user has selected on the site. Is prefers-color-scheme more going off device preference?

the prefers-color-scheme is about a setting of the specific profile of the specific browser.. but actually in terms of accessibility you are respecting the user choice system wide without interfering with its customization. If you instead wish to deal with your own setting, the localStorage is more suitable than sessionStorage because pesists when the browser is closed and reopened

Yeah it's for a bit of fun/portfolio so I think I can do the later in hindsight. Anything more commercial agree with the other approach as to not interfere with user preference. Thanks again!

One way of doing that is storing the theme mode in your localStorage.
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast-toggle');
const initTheme = localStorage.getItem('dark-mode');

if (initTheme === 'true') {
    html.classList.add('dark-mode');
}

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    html.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

    localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', html.classList.contains('dark-mode'));
});

*If the browser's localStorage though gets cleared, this won't be maintained. A more permanent solution would be to have an API that stores the value in a DB per user (something like userPreferences)

Thanks for the reply, that's interesting and good to know for future! But I guess if the user lefts the page and reopens, it will reset? Which is what I'm trying to avoid. I did question if this was possible at all on such a simple/static HTML site. So maybe I just need to accept it won't be without a more complex solution/setup

No it won’t reset. They will have to clear browser data for it to reset. Test it out ;)

Ah ok, I tried and it remembered when I clicked the logo and the back refreshed (macOS/Chrome). But if I left the page and entered the URL again it was back to default/white

You are right, u need localStorage instead of sessionStorage. sessionStorage is maintained only for the current session.. updating my answer

@user1406440 updated! Sorry for the mix up

Nice that looks like it works well - thanks for all the help on that. Notice it doesn't work in Safari but guess that's just Safari doing Safari things and maybe doesn't allow localStorage by default like other browsers? Which I'm fine with, just wondering! :)

Actually I think Safari works, it was just maybe caching like crazy! :)

You are going to need JavaScript, check out LocalStorage
